# escape dot in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

jQuery selector can't select an ID if it contains a `.` in it.
in my application ID name generates dynamically from usernames.

**How can I escape any special character from tag IDs** so that jQuery selector works well?

for example, ID1: `This.Is.ID.1`
ID2: `This.is.Another.ID`

Can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regex escape is a single \

Comment: could you please write full line code of regex.

Comment: What exactly is the situation where you need this? First you talk about jQuery selectors, but then you ask how to escape dots in regex.

Comment: jQuery selector can't select, so I need to escape IDs to tell jquery work with escaped IDs. I think this is the way, not sure ... :(

Comment: RTFM: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ "To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to modify a string that contains periods to have \\ in front of every period, to be supported as an id in the jQuery selector. Here is how to do that:

```
var username = 'some.username.with.dots';

// Replace all periods with \\. to 
username = username.replace(/\./g, '\\\\.');

// find element that matches #some\\.username\\.with\\.dots
$('#' + username).doSomethingWithjQuery();
```

- `.` means "any character" in regex, so you need to escape it by putting `\` in front.
- The `g` regex modifier means greedy, without it the replace expression would only replace the first `.` with `\\.`

**Edit**
I tried my code, and it seems like you need to change the replace value to `\\\\.` to make it become `\\.`

[image: JS Console]

Comment: I'm not sure if breaking one ugly line out into three ugly lines is better or worse.  Perhaps it would be better to write a small jQuery extension that hides this ugliness.  Something like `$.SelectAndEscape('#some.username.with.dots', '.')`...

Comment: i just want to escape `.` , your code works completely well for me. thank you.

Answer (score 12):

The official jQuery FAQ has that exact question: **[How do I select an element by an ID that has characters used in CSS notation?](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/)** They even have a function to help you escape. Quoting it:

> ... The colon ("`:`") and period ("`.`") are problematic within the context of a jQuery selector because they indicate a pseudo-class and class, respectively.
>
> In order to tell jQuery to treat these characters literally rather than as CSS notation, **they must be "escaped" by placing two backslashes in front of them**.

```
// Does not work:
$( "#some:id" )
 
// Works!
$( "#some\\:id" )
 
// Does not work:
$( "#some.id" )
 
// Works!
$( "#some\\.id" )
```

The following function takes care of escaping these characters and places a "#" at the beginning of the ID string:

```
function jq( myid ) {
    return "#" + myid.replace( /(:|\.|\[|\]|,|=)/g, "\\$1" );
}
```

The function can be used like so:

```
$( jq( "some.id" ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\\` (double backslash) to escape special characters.

```
$('#this\\.something')
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyhFa/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) states that two backslashes are used to escape them.

So your example would use `$("#This\\.Is\\.ID\\.1")`

Comment: "Periods shouldn't be used for classes or IDs". I suppose it may not be advisable, but it's perfectly valid HTML.

Comment: You are correct, sir: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id -- I'll tweak my answer.

Comment: You've got an HTML4 link there. Here are the HTML5 [`id` link](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute) and [`class` link](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#classes) with a definition of ["space separated tokens"](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#set-of-space-separated-tokens) that the `class` link references.

Answer (score -1):

You don't actually need to remote the .'s from the id.  You simply need to escape any special characters in the selector.  For example, to select the following element:

```
<div id='foo.bar'></div>
```

... you can use:

```
$('#foo\\.bar');
```