# Dynamically generate jQuery select statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have multiple of a particular tag. For example, we'll go for 100 of them as I'm trying to get clear examples not specific to my application but that I could apply to other uses if needed.

So maybe we have 100 divs, all with ordered ids in such a fashion:

```
<div id = '1'></div>
<div id = '2'></div>
.
.
.
<div id = '99'></div>
<div id = '100'></div>
```

Given a starting value, maybe I want to select the one 6 spaces before it and change its class or style. So something like:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var new = id-6;
$('#new').addClass('');//line
```

That line is what I want to figure out. I essentially want to pass that calculated value as the id to be searched for in a jQuery selector. Can this be done?

Comment: And yes, I'm aware new is a reserved word in javascript, but it gets the point across

Comment: `newId` gets the point across better and saves you the harassment.

Comment: Just as a general tip, take care when the [id has special chars: escape them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19596896/1850609).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're soo close..one small change

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var new = id-6;
$('#'+new).addClass('');//line
```

The jQuery object will parse strings, so passing in `'#'+new` will work.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure if that would work. I will check this as soon as it lets me