# Asp .net MVC - Javascript : Get html element with composite id attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, signalr

I'm stuck with a problem that seems too simple to be true. I'm wondering where is my mistake...

I'm rendering some HTML with RAZOR from Asp .net MVC controler

```
@foreach (var inst in Model.InstrumentsList)
{
  <section class="instrumSummary">
    <p>@inst.RemoteMachineName</p>
    <p>@inst.LocalClientName</p>
    <p id="rcState_@inst.LocalClientName">@inst.RemoteServiceState</p>
    <p id="rcVer">@inst.RemoteServiceVersion</p>
  </section>
}
```

Then, using jQuery I try to retreive elements in a signalR callback

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("document loaded !!");
    // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
    var chat = $.connection.InstHub;
    // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
    chat.client.SendInstrumentState = function (acState, targetHost) {
        // Add the message to the page.
        console.log(targetHost + " : " + acState);
        var idupd = "rcState_" + targetHost;
        console.log("update element id :" + idupd);
        $("#" + idupd).text(acState);
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        console.log("Hub is started.");
    });
});
</script>
```

The problem is that i can't get to retreive my `<p>` tag when its `id` attribute is defined with a static part (`rcState_`) and a dynamic part coming from my model (`@inst.LocalClientName`)

So basicaly the `$("#" + idupd)` does not return my `<p>` html element. When I replace its ID attribute with a full static name (for exemple `<p id="rcstate">`), everything works fine, but as this element will be repeated n times depending on the number of elements in my list, I should be able to update the correct element when executing signalR callback.

Of course in the code above I checked that `targetHost` and `@inst.LocalClientName` have exactly the same values...

Comment: Why not decorate your p elements with a special class, then you can grab them by className instead?

Comment: Are you sure that `$("#" + idupd)` it's unique on the page? Maybe you are retrieving a list of items. Use chrome dev tools to debug what elements it's retrieving

Comment: Yep, I have  already checked with the chrome debugger. My page contains onlythe list of object and there was only one object in the list. With the debugger I can see the id attribute being valorized properly

Comment: I have to check but i think that's because the @inst.LocalclientName wich is "ihw.rsn:xxxx.lmn:yyyyy"

Comment: ok tha't it, got confirmation from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596610/escape-dot-in-javascript